# Please point out the inaccuracies in my reasoning

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, real-numbers

I am making notes on real analysis by using propositions and truth tables. I decided to make it in this way in order to present a straightforward and convincing proofs even for skeptical students. The content is taken from [the video lecture series of this website](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/audio-video-courses/mathematics/Mathematics-I-IIT-Kanpur/lecture-06.html). Lecture 1 talks about properties of real numbers. The lecture starts with a very short introduction to real numbers followed by the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

I decided to replace this very short introduction with two lengthy sections.

1. [Logic and Elementary Set Theory](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gv4b3k9vo3mrzrw/1._Logic_and_Elementary_Set_Theory.pdf/file)
2. [Real Numbers](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ghkon72hoqx2nv6/2._Real_Numbers.pdf/file)

In the first section, I discuss statements, elementary set theory and some elementary aspects of logic 101.

I would kindly request the reader to go through section 1 and section 2 and point out the inaccuracies in my reasoning.

Comment: The mathematical notion of *set* is a collection of abstract (i.e. mathematical) objects, not "real life" ones.

Comment: "Right now I do not have a definition of object. " You cannot define **everything**. The mathematical theory of sets assumes the notion of set as primitive (undefined).

Comment: "that infinite collection cannot be imagined" The origin of modern set theory, with Cantor and Dedekind start exactly from the "imagination" of the infinite (endless) sequence of natural numbers as "collected" into a single entity: class, set.

Comment: Please someone answer....

Comment: Please someone answer ...

Comment: I've browsed Section 1: the presentation of truth table is not very clear. Page 1: "The statement (A) is one of the rows in the
following (excluding green row)" Pag 4: "Denote
collection of two statements by (A, B). (A, B) is one of the rows in the following (excluding green row)".Compare with some introductory textbook and [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). Page 5: "A ˄ B is the only row in the following 2-ITT" sounds wrong.

Comment: For an elementary introduction to logic aimed at a first course in mathematics, the 3-adic and 4-adic connectives are quite useless.

Comment: The sub-section dedicated to negation must be expanded and the example with quantifiers can be complicated, because quantifiers have not been introduced yet.

Comment: Thanks... section 1 is problematic as I expected. But I bet section 2 is not that problematic. Please go through section 2 and explain the imperfections in an answer... please